# Google sheets: How do I concat a string in apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I concat a value that is being copied over to another sheet?

Sheet 1>> Input Example (column B contains Product Name, and column C contains Color): 
Col B | Col C
Shoes | Black

Sheet 2>> Desired Output Example: 
Col E (concated values)
Shoes - Black

```
    function onEdit(e) {
      const sh=e.range.getSheet();
      if(sh.getName()=="Sheet 1" && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value=="TRUE") {
        const tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet 2');
        const nr=tsh.getLastRow()+1;

//Concat Shoes with the value below
        sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,3,1,1).copyTo(tsh.getRange(nr,5,1,1));

     
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of columns "B" and "C" from the edited row of the column "A" of "Sheet 1", and you want to put the value to the column "E" of "Sheet 2" by merging them.

In order to achieve this, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,3,1,1).copyTo(tsh.getRange(nr,5,1,1));
```

#### To:

```
const value = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2, 1, 2).getValues()[0].join(" - ");
tsh.getRange(nr, 5, 1, 1).setValue(value);
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)